# Using Golang json.NewDecoder / json.NewEncoder

Tags: json, go

I'm a total noob at go and I'm trying to understand what I'm missing here.  I'm expecting to use `dec.Decode` to loop over the json values and end up with a map of the response.  What I'm getting is the entire json string as the key to the first element of the map.  What am I missing?

Example response:

`2015/03/02 10:03:16 map[error:invalid_request error_description:that is not a recognized WePay API call error_code:1001] map[string]interface {}`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var v map[string]interface{}
    resp, err := http.Get("https://wepayapi.com/v2/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error: " + err.Error())
    }   
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // resp.Body is an io.ReadCloser... NewDecoder expects an io.Reader
    dec := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)

    // Decode reads the next JSON-encoded value from its input and stores it in the value pointed to by v.
    for err := dec.Decode(&v); err != nil && err != io.EOF; {
        log.Println("ERROR: " + err.Error())
        return
    }   
    log.Println(v, reflect.TypeOf(v))
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample, or the structure of the json returned?

Comment: From what I see, you clearly have a map with three keys, `error`, `error_description` and `error_code`. Just print `len(v)` or `v["error_code"]`.

Comment: It was decoding the JSON correctly all long.  I was reading the log line as essentially map["error_description:that is not a recognized WePay API call error_code:1001 error:invalid_request"] (the key as the entire JSON string) instead of it being a map with these 3 values.  Bottom line I'm an idiot ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Decoder` will decode the whole `JSON` value at once (in this case the error object), you don;y have to call it in a loop:

```
if err := dec.Decode(&v); err != nil {
    log.Println("ERROR: " + err.Error())
    return
}
```

As a response you get a map equavalent of this `JSON`:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"that is not a recognized WePay API call","error_code":1001}
```

Result:

```
map[string]interface{} {
    "error":"invalid_request",
    "error_description":"that is not a recognized WePay API call",
    "error_code":1001,
}
```

Comment: How to retrieve individual values from this interface?

Comment: @VinitGaikwad `result["error"].(string)` and similar for the others